# How to send HTTP (GET) request in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to send HTTP (GET) request to a URL in background without waiting response.

App sends a request, so user can close the app. Script on url at this time will process the request. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm guessing, then, that your app doesn't depend at all on the output of this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSMutableURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` block to send asynchronous requests in background. Inside of the if block you can check either it is success or not.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourURLHere.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *rspreportStatus, NSData *datareportStatus, NSError *e)
{
     if (e == nil)
     {
         // SUCCESS
     } else {
         // NOT SUCCESS
     }
}];
```